# How to handle the intersection of the XOR operation

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, signal-processing

### Context

I'm trying to recreate an effect used on photoshop called satin effect, which creates stainy texture by creating a satin texture (or structure) and applying a blur-like effect.

**Example :**

[image: Example]


I think this effect is achieved by using a **double shift of the input pattern** from which they apply a **XOR operation** to get the satin pattern (See Image above - Satin Size 0), then I think they apply a gaussian blur while handling the intersection of the XOR operation.

### What I've done so far

I created the first part which consist of shifting the pattern of the satin.
 Here's the code :
**Image Used :** [apple.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owdd2.png)

```python
apple = cv2.imread('apple.png')
apple = cv2.cvtColor(apple, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# User Inputs (Similar to Photoshop)
angle = 41        # angle of the shift
distance = 100    # distance of the shift

angle = np.deg2rad(180-angle)
tx, ty = (distance*np.cos(angle),distance*np.sin(angle))

# Shifting
shift_matrix1 = np.array([[1,0,tx],[0,1,ty]], dtype=np.float32)
shift_matrix2 = np.array([[1,0,-tx],[0,1,-ty]], dtype=np.float32)

shift1 = cv2.warpAffine(apple, shift_matrix1, apple.shape)
shift2 = cv2.warpAffine(apple,shift_matrix2, apple.shape)

# XOR Operation
xor_result = cv2.bitwise_not(cv2.bitwise_and(cv2.bitwise_xor(shift1, shift2), apple))

output = cv2.bitwise_and(xor_result, apple)
```

Which gives us the expected result *(similar to what we achieve with photoshop)* :

[image: result1]

**Problem :**
But the problem emerge when I try to apply the gaussian blur before the XOR operation (Which can be achieved by adding those two lines of code **before the XOR operation** :

```python
...

shift1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(shift1, (101,101),0)
shift2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(shift2, (101,101),0)

# XOR Operation
xor_result = ...
```

**And her's what I get :**

[image: example2]

**Vs What I get using Photoshop :**

[image: example photoshop]

---

### Question

So I think that I'm missing an operation to handle the intersection of those 2 shapes (where we got those weird pixels)
**So my question is :** What operation do you think we should add in order to handle the intersection of the XOR of these two shapes ?

Comment: You’re using bitwise operations, you likely need to use MIN and MAX operations instead. MIN is the gray-scale equivalent of the AND Boolean operator, and MAX that of the OR.

Comment: I never really thought what the XOR equivalent could be. Maybe you could use the absolute difference for XOR.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by the absolute difference for the XOR

Comment: Nice remark ! I tried to use MIN and MAX rather than XOR operation and it worked. Even if the result is not perfectly similar to what we get with photoshop but at least we got rid of those weird pixels on the intersection. Here's the output : [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnYto.png). Any Idea of what can be added in order to get the exact same result ?

Comment: Absolute difference between a and b is `abs(a-b)`.

Comment: Yeah I know the formula, but I don't understand how can we use this as XOR nor on the XOR

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246543/discussion-between-saulgoodman-and-cris-luengo).

Comment: I'm suggesting that `xor(a,b)` could be replaced with `abs(a-b)`. If one of the two is 0, the other's value is retained. If they are identical, it results in 0. Otherwise it results in some intermediate value. I think that is exactly what the gray-scale extension of XOR should do.

Comment: Here are 3 definitions for a fuzzy XOR operation: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.entcs.2009.07.045 -- the first one, `max(x-y,y-x)` is equivalent to my suggestion. You can also try the other ones, `min(2-x-y,x+y)` or `(1-x)*y+x*(1-y)`.

Comment: Thank you ! This is the right formulas for this use case `max(x-y,y-x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fuzzy logic version of the Boolean `or` operator is the `max` operator, and that of the `and` is `min`.

For XOR, the most logical equivalent is `max(x-y, y-x)`, more efficiently written as `abs(x-y)`. [This paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.entcs.2009.07.045) describes two other options, but the absolute difference seems to reproduce the Photoshop effect just fine.

I would thus implement your code as:

```py
xor_result = cv2.absdiff(shift1, shift2)
output = np.minimum(255 - xor_result, apple)
```